# Clear A Bitmap in .Net

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, gdi+, graphics2d

I'm using PictureBox control to draw complicated charts, and to optimize for performance i use a cache Bitmap for each layer of the drawing, and draw them on the control image, the upper layers have transparent backgrounds, i need to clear them and redraw on every change.

Assuming g instance of Graphics class of the Bitmap, using `g.Clear(Color.White)` draws a white rectangle over everything and so hiding lower layers, and `g.Clear(Color.Transparent)` draws Transparent rectangle over, what means doing nothing.

Isn't there a way to clear the Bitmap returning it to its original state?

Comment: If they don't change as often, I would consider drawing the lower levels into a bitmap which I show as the PictureBox.Image or even BackgroundImage. Other than tha I don't thik there is a way around drawing all the bitmaps that make up the total image whenever any one changes. You can cache not only the single layers but also their composites, though; but you still will need to re-create all bitmaps from the changed layer on upwards. - Btwe: I'm not sure about your choice of word : Looks like you are not so much asking about clearing a __Bitmap__ but parts or all of your composite graphics?

Comment: whenever a change takes place (say movement) i re-draw the shapes in the layer where the change is (after clearing it with its background color) on their layer's cache image, then draw all layers' images from down upwards on the picturebox.image, when clearing a layer's image with any color other than "transparent" it's ok, but if the layer is transparent (because it's an overlay layer), the moved shape is still drawn in both positions (the old and the new).

Comment: Let's make that clear: You are drawing all those layers onto the top of the one pb? not the image? no nested panles? (which are a nice way to avoid much of the redrawing..)

Comment: all layers are drawn on the pictureBox.image

Comment: OK; what numbers are we talking about, i.e. how approximately many layers and what bitmap size?

Comment: 2 or 3 layers, bitmap of about 600*500

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106809/discussion-between-taw-and-mohamed-selim).

Comment: Oh it's ended, the problem was just that I've used the wrong Graphics object, it was g of the picturebox.image not of the layer image, and g.clear(color.Transparent) works perfectly. many thanks for your help any way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is maybe not the answer you were looking for but I think it is an insteresting alternative to what you have.

Instead of having to draw all the layers upwards from every change, I stack as many layers on top of each other by **nesting** a number of `PictureBoxes` into one bottom `PictureBox pBox0`:

```
List<PictureBox> Layers = new List<PictureBox>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Layers.Add(pBox0);
    setUpLayers(pBox0 , 20);  // stacking 20 layers onto the botton one
    timer1.Start();           // simulate changes
}
```

The stacking is set up like this:

```
void setUpLayers(Control parent, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
        pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        pb.Size = parent.ClientSize;
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pb.Size.Width,pb.Size.Height,PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
        pb.Image = bmp;
        pb.Parent = i == 0 ? pBox0 : Layers[i - 1];
        Layers.Add(pb);
    }
}
```

For best performance I use `Format32bppPArgb` as the pixel format.

For testing I run a `Tick` event that randomly draws onto a layer:

```
Random R = new Random(9);
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int l = R.Next(Layers.Count-1) + 1;

    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) Layers[l].Image;
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(Layers[l].Image))
    {
        G.Clear(Color.Transparent);
        using (Font font = new Font("Consolas", 33f))
        G.DrawString(l + " " + DateTime.Now.Second , font, Brushes.Gold, 
            R.Next(bmp.Size.Width),  R.Next(bmp.Size.Height));
    }
    Layers[l].Image = bmp;
}
```

To collect all layers into one Bitmap you would make use of the `DrawToBitmap` method:

```
Bitmap GetComposite(Control ctl)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ctl.ClientSize.Width, ctl.ClientSize.Height,
                            PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    ctl.DrawToBitmap(bmp, ctl.ClientRectangle);
    return bmp;
}
```

The result can then be saved or used in any other way..

Note that creating too many layers this way will hit a limit for window handles; I hit that limit at around 90 layers. If you need more that a few dozen layers a more intricate caching strategy is called for..

Answer (score 6):

```
private void btn_CancelImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Cancel and delete this Image?", "Cancel", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            ClearImage();
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    public void ClearImage()
    {
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(ImageBitmap);
        g.Clear(Color.White);
    }
```